# Magento 1: Last logged In - Wrong Year

Tags: magento-1.9, log

This is Magento 1.9.2.4 out of the box without any other custom changes. I discovered today in Magento Admin Panel -> Customers -> Customer View tab -> Personal Information section that "Last Logged In" shows a wrong year. For example:

Last Logged In: Jul 21, **9200** 6:00:55 PM (Offline)

As you can see the year has a problem. Everything was working great last week I suspect this is happening from the operating system on the server not from Magento. Without no updates or changes in the code (I am the only one having access as root to this server) this is the only reason I suspect.

Did anyone have this issue before?

Comment: maybe the customer was from the future, which is good news for all us Magento 1.x users, we dont't have to migrate to 2.x for at least another 7,183 years... :)

Comment: It is not the only customer, there are many of them.  I searched the database and there are no issues related to the recorded dates. Year is correct in log tables. I will disable the log for a while and clearing the tables to see what is happening.

Comment: seriously I have not seen a date get so screwed up as that. I take it you have checked your os date is correct. What server os are you running. Perhaps a system restart is required.

Comment: OS is just fine. This is a bug in Magento core files. I am digging right know. This is one link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454879/magento-1-9-wrong-customer-created-and-last-login-dates, this is another one http://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-bug-magento-customer-create-date-juxtaposition/.

Comment: Yep, looks like a bug...

Comment: @ADDISON74 how can i reproduce it?

Comment: @sv3n - go to Backend -> System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> General. In Locale Options set Timezone to GTB Standard Time (Europe/London). In Customers -> Manage Customers choose any customer account. In Customer View -> Personal Information section there are two rows now: "Last Logged In: " and Last Logged In (Europe/London): ". The issue appears on the first row, the second one shows correctly the time.

Comment: I just truncated all the log tables found in /shell/log.php file. Now the first row shows (Offline), the second row shows Jul 22, 2017 11:31:33 AM (Offline). Something happened, the time is gone from first row in all accounts who logged in today, it is (Online) or (Offline). In my opinion I give credit to those who solved this bug in the code. A 9200 year means a wrong interpretation of a string from database.

Comment: Just wanted to know how to reproduce .... i guess there will be a pull request at magento-lts soon :P

Comment: I agree, magento-lts is doing the hard job which Magento maintenance team should do.